# Parser error with jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code it returns a parser error and fails.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax',
  dataType: 'json'
});

$('#addHotlink').click(function() {
  $('body').after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px;"><div><h3>Choose a name for your hotlink:<img id="lightBoxClose" src="http://www.example.com/images/closedAccordion.png" height="17" width="17" alt="" title="Close this box" /></h3><form id="addHotlinkForm" action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off"><input id="hotlinkName" type="text" maxlength="15" /><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add Hotlink" /></form></div></div>');
  $('#lightBox').hide().fadeIn('fast');
  return false;
});

$('#addHotlinkForm').live('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var pageURL = window.location.href;  
  var hotlinkName = $('#hotlinkName').val();

  if (hotlinkName.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      data: {
        hotlinkName: hotlinkName, 
        hotlinkURL: pageURL
      },
      success: function() {

        alert('Your hotlink ' + hotlinkName + ' has been inserted to the url: ' + pageURL);
      },
      error: function (ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        alert(thrownError);
        alert('Var hotlinkName: ' + hotlinkName + ' Var hotlinkURL: ' + pageURL);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I get a parser error when it tries to execute? Although in the error function the values are being returned as:

hotlinkName: Text entered into box,

hotlinkURL: The current address of page (http://www.example.com/home)

Why is this not working? I have tried changing the type to POST and it still doesn't work?

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to do, but of course it fails as it is not linked to any ajax sheet.

http://jsfiddle.net/novactown/QsDVe/

Comment: Are you attempting to use `.ajax()` to connect to a different domain? This will be prevented to avoid cross-site scripting attacks, unless the user's browser specifically allows it.

Comment: Using something like Firebug or Dev tools, get a copy of the JSON being returned and send it through jsonlint.com to find out what the errors are. More importantly: you're not doing anything with the JSON, so why retrieve it? If you just need a success callback, you don't need to retrieve type 'json'.

Comment: -1 You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708602/jquery-ajax-json-and-sending-over-window-location-href

Comment: @Greg Ye changed that now, can I not send over variables like http://www.example.com/home

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, if you are using jsfiddle to test your script change the ajaxsetup to the following

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    type: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/qKtkm/) : a simple environment to test ajax based javascript using JQuery on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You can checkout the jsfiddle [documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json) for more.

Comment: If you are making an ajax call to different site then you WOULD have to use jsonp as per @mblase75 's comment